# Facebook: obtain user's locale

Tags: facebook

In Facebook Web Games with **FB JS SDK** how one obtains user's locale, i.e. language user prefers to speak to render a game with?

Tried these but none of it worked:

```
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        { fields: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,locale,picture'},
        r => console.log( 'FB /me:', r ),
    )
```

Prints everything but locale. And:

```
FB.login( response => console.log( 'locale:', response.authResponse.user.locale ) )
```

where **response.authResponse** doesn't have **user** field at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locale` isn’t available any more, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0/#gapi-change:

> The following default fields have replaced public_profile: […]
>
> As a result, the following fields that belonged to public_profile are deprecated:
>   - […]
>   - locale
>   - […]

.

> where response.authResponse doesn't have user field at all

Not supposed to any more either, you only get a `userID`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus#response_and_session_objects

Comment: Thank you for answer and rigorous references! What's the best way now to obtain user's locale?

Comment: There is no other way. You’ll need to create your own way to let the user chose their preferred language. (Maybe start with an educated guess based on the Accept-Language header their browser might be sending; but you should always offer them a way to switch manually.)